# angular 2 rc4 creating variable after getting data from Http observable

Tags: angular, angular2-http

im kinda new in angular2, i hope you could help me im pretty sure it must be something simple but this is the deal im making a service that could handle http calls but its needed to apply some filters after the data is loaded without asking once again to the api server with new parameters basically i wanna let angular2 handle that part

Update**

> Service
>
> `httpHandler(type,model){var token = this.LoginService.JwtDecoded();
>         var authHeader = new Headers();
>         authHeader.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);`
>
> ```
>  return this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1/api/service/'+model, {
>       headers: authHeader
>       })
>   .map((res: Response) => res.json());    }
> ```
>
> Component
>
> ```
> this.Request.httpHandler('get','receiver/')
> .subscribe(
>     data => this.data = data, <-- from here
>     err => this.error = 'there is a mistake!',
>     () => console.log(this.data) <-- this one is outputing just what i want
>   );
> console.log(data); <-- i wanna output the same result in here
> ```

So, how can i capture the api result into a variable?

update**
I wanna output 'this.data' outside subscribe, weird thing is that i can output inside subscribe and in the html as well but i need to do some stuff with that json before outputing in the html.. any idea guys? thanks!

Thanks for your time guys, very appreciated.

Comment: In order to have a Minimum, Complete, and Verifiable example, you should really detail what your current problem is. What does it do now and why is that wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a service to fetch the data

```js
// xyz.service.ts

import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  private url = `receiver/`;

  constructor(private http: Http) {
  }

  getData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.url)
      .map((res: Response) => res.json());
  }
}
```

Now use that service in the component.

```js
//xyz.component.ts

import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

import {DataService} from './xyz.service';

import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home-content',
  templateUrl: 'xyz.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['xyz.component.scss'],
  providers: [DataService, HTTP_PROVIDERS]
})
export class HomeContentComponent implements OnInit {
  private data: Object;

  constructor(private _dataService: DataService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._dataService.getData().subscribe(data => {
      this.data = data;
    });
  }
}
```

Now the data will be available in `this.data`

Comment: thanks ritz i tried to do what u said and i couldnt make it work, the weird thing is that i can output inside subscribe or in the html like data?.name but i cant output outside subscribe in the very same function.. do you have any idea ??

Comment: Thats because its an asynchronous function. If you want to anything with the data, you will have to do it inside subscribe. Its accessible in HTML because angular automatically updates the view when it detects that `this.data` has changed. I would prefer you call a function from inside subscribe and do whatever you want to do with `this.data` inside it as then it will be available.